# Search Bar in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there is way we can customize search bar in teams so it can also show content from other sources ?

I am trying to check documentation but its looks it only limited to team search not other sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to customize search bar in Teams.

If you wish, you may suggest this feature on - [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: So search in teams only limited to Teams messages and files and people ?

Comment: Yes, its limited to Teams scope only.